async await blocks execution even with task.WaitAsync
In my WPF application (.NET 8.0) I want to consume a asynchronous operation from a 3rd party library. When testing with all code inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs it works smoothely. When I move the same code into a separate class, using a static constructor, the operation is blocking indefinitely even with WaitAsync.
Here is my code:
  public class VirtuosoCommunication
  {
    ..
    public static VirtuosoCommunication? Create(...)
    {
      VirtuosoCommunication vc = new VirtuosoCommunication();
      // setting private variables for vc

      if (!vc.TestRead(log)) return null;
      if (!vc.TestWrite(log)) return null;

      return vc;
    }

    private bool TestRead(Log? log)
    {
      string testGraph = "...";
      Task<Graph?> task = LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(testGraph, log);
            
      Graph? g = task.Result;
      return g != null;
    }

    internal async Task<Graph?> LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(string graphFullName, Log? log)
    {
      Uri baseUri = new Uri(_readEndpoint ?? "");

      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.BaseAddress = baseUri;

      SparqlQueryClient sparqlQueryClient = new SparqlQueryClient(client, baseUri);

      Graph result = new Graph();
      IGraph? tmp = null;

      try
      {
        while (tmp == null || tmp.Triples.Count == limit)
        {
          string query = "construct { ?s ?p ?o } FROM <" + graphFullName + "> where {?s ?p ?o.} OFFSET " + offSet.ToString() + " LIMIT " + limit.ToString();
          Task<IGraph> task = sparqlQueryClient.QueryWithResultGraphAsync(query);
          tmp = await task.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));

          ...
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) { ... }

      return result;
    }

When I run the code line by line, it stops executing at tmp = await task.WaitAsync. When I then hit the "Break execution" Button in Visual Studio, it is showing me the line Graph? g = task.Result in the TestRead method to be the next to be executed when the thread returns.
As I said, the same async call in a test routine completely placed in MainWindow.xaml.cs works without problem, so I guess I am somehow using the async call wrongly.
UPDATE 25.11.2024
From the answer of this question I changed the TestRead method to:
private bool TestRead(Log? log)
{
  string testGraph = "...";
  //Task<Graph?> task = LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(testGraph, log);
  Task<Graph?> task = Task.Run<Graph?>(async() => await LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(testGraph, log));

        
  Graph? g = task.Result;
  return g != null;
}

It works this way (yeah!), but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Regarding parallelization, I just need the call to the SPARQL endpoint to not block my UI, I don't need to run other, parallel tasks meanwhile.

"Graph? g = task.Result;" - just one example where this screams for a deadlock. Await your tasks and go async all the way.

"using a static constructor" - you are not using a static ctor. This is a factory method. Sounds pedantic but there is a significant enough difference there to point it out.

this is a classic deadlock caused by .Result; don't do that

On a side note: QueryWithResultGraphAsync accepts a cancellation token, why don't you just use that for timeouts?

@Fildor: Thanks for your replies! I did some more research about async/await (I was just using it because of the 3rd party lib that provides the QueryWithResultGraphAsync-method. Until now, I used the Background-Worker for asynchronous operations) and learned about the context-blocking problem.
Also, it is not pedantic to point out my wrong usage of concept names. Especially as programmer it is very mandatory to use exact language, as the machine is not doing what we want, but what we tell it to do. So I am happy to get guidance beyond my question!

@MarcGravell: Thanks for your reply! I understand that the blocking is because of the usage of the same context of both methods. But how do I get the result from the async method, as it returns a Task<[typeOfResult]>? Is it enough to just make the QueryWithResultGraphAsync use the threadpool by ConfigureAwait(false) and make the TestRead method async as well? Wouldn't I need to make methods async all the way up in call hierarchy in that case?

@Charlieface thanks for your reply! I wasn't using cancellation token, as this is my first async/await usage and I still try to get my head around. I understand cancellation token as a way to cancel the operation from my code (f.e. user input), but I would just  want the operation to cancel after a given time, so I was assuming to just configure the call in that way. And the timeout-thing is only the next topic on the list, I just wanted to make the method running at first. I'll look into cancellation token next.

You can create a CancellationTokenSource with a specified timeout, or set one using .CancelAfter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-9.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-ctor(system-int32)

I found a solution that avoids the deadlock (see UPDATE), now, is this the right way to do it or just a dirty quickhack?

That covers up the problem instead of fixing it. It's not await that blocks. The UI thread is already doing something else so await can't return to it. And that something is most likely Graph? g = task.Result in TestRead, which in turn awaits for the async operations to complete. You *must* make TestReadasynchronous to avoid blocking the UI thread.ConfigureAwait(false)will also help by not getting back to the UI thread, butTestRead` certainly is buggy

@Aaginor Richard Deeming's answer shows the correct solution. Have you tried it? Have you encountered any problems? That's how .NET applications work since 2012, this isn't something untested

@PanagiotisKanavos yes, I tried (and understand) Richards answer and it works nice. I know it is not new to .NET, it is just "new" to me, as I was usually using the BackgroundWorker class for asynchronous calls, but had now to go with async await, as I need to consume a async method from a 3rd party library

As Fildor said in the comments, you're not using a static cctor; you're using a static factory method.
And that's a good thing. A ctor or cctor cannot be async, so you wouldn't be able to await anything. But a factory method can be async. And in this case, it should be:
public static async Task<VirtuosoCommunication?> Create(...)
{
    VirtuosoCommunication vc = new VirtuosoCommunication();
    // setting private variables for vc

    if (!await vc.TestRead(log)) return null;
    if (!await vc.TestWrite(log)) return null;

    return vc;
}

private async Task<bool> TestRead(Log? log)
{
    string testGraph = "...";
    Graph? g = await LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(testGraph, log);
    return g != null;
}


Next, I'd suggest looking at your HttpClient usage, which is problematic:

You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software | ASP.NET Monsters
You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software

You should consider using IHttpClientFactory instead of creating a new HttpClient instance on every call.
Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests - .NET | Microsoft Learn

Hey Richard, thanks a lot for your reply! You help me get my head around the async/await concepts. If I understand it correctly, I have to make all the methods async up the call hierarchy. Wouldn't I run in the same deadlock issue when calling my factory? Until which point up the call hierarchy would I need to go with async? Would it be enough until I hit a method that returns void (so I don't have to wait for a result)? My method LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint returns a Task variable. Why can you asign it directly to a Graph variable, not Task?

Thank you also for pointing out the problem with the HttpClient usage. I was not aware of that and check out the Factory!

Ideally, it should be async all the way up. However, there are issues with async void methods, which rules out event handlers. And constructors can't be async at all. At those points, you would usually either store or discard a Task returned from a "real" async method. See David Fowler's advice on GitHub for examples.

I see, I am gonne change my application to use ApplicationStartup event instead of MainWindow to be able to call the methods to load my data in an await async way.
What still puzzles me: In Graph? g = await LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(testGraph, log); you assign the return value (a Task<Graph?>) to a Graph? variable, not a Task<Graph?> ... how is that possible?

I researched IHttpClientFactory a bit and understand that I should use that to create my HttpClient. But I somehow failed to find an implementation for the IHttpClientFactory. I'd assumed, that there should be some standard implementations? Or do I have to implement the interface by myself?
As I am in control of the WebAPI, that I call ... would it also be enough to just use a static HttpClient (I have a static controller class anyways)? The URL won't ever change

@Aaginor you can only see the interface, the implementation is internal and will be wired up via dependency injection. I found reference code here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs but depending on your hosting scenario the implementation you're using might be different (I'm not that familiar with WPF on .NET 8)

@Aaginor "In Graph? g = await LoadGraphFromSparqlRemoteEndpoint(testGraph, log); you assign the return value (a Task<Graph?>) to a Graph? variable, not a Task<Graph?> ... how is that possible?" - That's just how async/await works. If you await a Task<T>, you get back the T, not the Task. :)

@Aaginor The IHttpClientFactory instance is provided via a NuGet package. You can see that the documentation lists "package-provided" for all supported frameworks, and points to the Microsoft.Extensions.Http package.

Your updated answer using Task.Run() is likely correct, but it is not completely clear without context:
When you're awaiting tasks with await DoSomething(); the current synchronization context is captured (if called from a button click in WPF, this will be the main thread). When the async operation completes, the state machine will schedule the next line of code to be executed in the same context (ie. the main thread). However, since your calling task.Result in TestRead you're already blocking the main thread, resulting in a deadlock.
Calling Task.Run() avoids this problem by making sure everything "inside" the Task.Run block is executed on the thread pool, which does not preserve synchronization context and will not deadlock as it will just spawn new threads if all of them are blocked.
Please note that it would still be better to use async / await all the way through and avoid Task.Result and Task.Wait() as much as possible. If you can change the TestRead function to return a Task instead (like Richard Deeming proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/79214898/1074014) definitely go for this approach!

It works, which isn't the same thing as being correct. It uses another thread to do what could be done by making TestRead asynchronous and using ConfigureAwait(false) in the async code. Richard Deeming's code shows the proper code for this

As I said, asynchronous code would be better. I'm not sure if Aaginor can change the semantics of the TestRead method or if it needs to be synchronous.
Edit: I made this part bold to be more clear about it, thanks for bringing it up!

Hey Dominik, thanks for the reply! I am in full control of the classes, so I can use async / await all the way up. I do not need the main thread, so using the threadpool seems to be a logical choice. Coming from BackgroundWorker, I need to get used to the async / await thing a bit, so it's good to get some more general insights regarding the mechanics and pitfalls :)
